# Content porter package reversing in 2011 SP1 in production environment

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is there a need (is it advisable) to have Content Porter (cp) server license in Production environment?

Does reversing package require CP Server license?

How much does it cost?

Answer (score 3):

It can be useful if you need to adjust a BluePrint or copy some of your production content to lower environments for testing purposes. It is more common to see the entire CM database backed up and restored to lower environments, but this may not be possible in all cases due to staggered work streams etc.

As for cost - you would need to contact your SDL Tridion sales representative.